# how to rotationally change the content of 'div' on mouseover on each 'li'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

whenever, I mouseover on the 'li', then, that particular 'li' attribute need to changed to 'clsSect'. On the other hand, based on the list[li] selection, the div content has to set to 'display:block' other should changed to 'display:none'.

if the first 'li' selected, then, the first 'div' need to be selected, likewise
if the second 'li' selected, then, the second 'div' need to be selected,

This below code does not work as expected. Any help please?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="mainBodyContent" id="Contact"> 
    <div class="perimgleft">
     <img class="perImg" alt="This is for sample"/>
     <div id="thisID3">
     <p><span>sample3</span></p>
    <p>To explore job opputunities at 'Company', see our <a name="Career" href="#Careers"><span>Hot Jobs</span></a></p>
     </div></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="mainBodyContent" id="About"> 
    <div class="perimgleft">
     <img class="perImg" alt="This is for sample"/>
     <div id="thisID2">
     <p><span>sample3</span></p>
    <p>To explore job opputunities at 'Company', see our <a name="Career" href="#Careers"><span>Hot Jobs</span></a></p>
     </div></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="mainBodyContent" id="Careers"> 
    <div class="perimgleft">
     <img class="perImg" alt="This is for sample"/>
     <div id="thisID1">
     <p><span>sample1</span></p>
    <p>To explore job opputunities at 'Company', see our <a name="Career" href="#Careers"><span>Hot Jobs</span></a></p>
     </div></div> 
    </div> 
    
    <div id="selRound">
    <ul class="clearfix rouncorner">
    <li id="fpn1" class="myList clsSect"></li>
    <li id="fpn2" class="myList"></li>
    <li id="fpn3" class="myList"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    
    <script>
    var $hover = $("div.perimgleft img");
    $hover1 = $("#Contact div[class='perimgleft'] div");$hover2 = $("#About div[class='perimgleft'] div");$hover3 = $("#Careers div[class='perimgleft'] div");
    
    $("#selRound .myList").mouseover(function(evt) {
         if(evt.currentTarget.id == 'fpn1'){
      $hover1.css('display', 'block');
      ($hover2, $hover3).css('display', 'none');
     }
     else if(evt.currentTarget.id == 'fpn2'){
      ($hover1, $hover3).css('display', 'none');
      $hover2.css('display', 'block');
     }else {
      ($hover1, $hover2).css('display', 'none');
      $hover3.css('display', 'block');
     } 
     
      });
      $("#selRound .myList").mouseout(function(evt) {


      });
     </script> 
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by selected? clicked or hovered?

Comment: Yes, I mean 'hover'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to clean up the code.

In HTML we set the ID for the contents we should hide/show

```
...
<div id="fpn1" class="perimgleft">
...
<div id="fpn2" class="perimgleft">
...
<div id="fpn3" class="perimgleft">
...
```

Then we use them as data attributes for list elements

```
<li data-show="#fpn1" class="myList">fpn1</li>
<li data-show="#fpn2" class="myList">fpn2</li>
<li data-show="#fpn3" class="myList">fpn3</li>
```

Then with jquery we hide all contents

```
$('.perimgleft').hide();
```

So that we'll show the right content related to the hovered element:

```
$('ul.clearfix.rouncorner li').mouseover(function(){
    $('ul.clearfix.rouncorner li').removeClass("clsSect");
    $(this).addClass("clsSect");
    var contentId = $(this).data("show");
    $('.perimgleft').hide();
    $(contentId).show();
})
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vuqk4y6e/)

Comment: Hi, will this code works in IE 8 as well please? Also, will this be a efficient DOM manipulation please?

Comment: Yes, it works on IE8, and yes, this solution require low DOM manipulation (just toggling class and hiding/showing some div)

Comment: this piece(above) of code is just a piece in large amount of codes. So, this code should be efficient DOM manipulation and this **should not be poor** DOM manipulation. Will above code satisfy that, please?

Comment: sure it is. i meant that

Comment: in case this answer helped you please mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var $hover = $("div.perimgleft img");
$hover1 = $("#Contact div[class='perimgleft']>div");$hover2 = $("#About div[class='perimgleft']>div");$hover3 = $("#Careers div[class='perimgleft']>div");

$("#selRound .myList").mouseover(function(evt) {
   if(evt.currentTarget.id == 'fpn1'){
   $hover1.css('display', 'block');
   $hover2.css('display', 'none');
   $hover3.css('display', 'none');
}
else if(evt.currentTarget.id == 'fpn2'){
    $hover3.css('display', 'none');
    $hover1.css('display', 'none');
    $hover2.css('display', 'block');
}else {
    $hover2.css('display', 'none');
    $hover1.css('display', 'none');
    $hover3.css('display', 'block');
} 

});
$("#selRound .myList").mouseout(function(evt) {
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
      .mainBodyContent{
        display: none;
      }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="selRound">
    <ul class="clearfix rouncorner">
        <li id="fpn1" class="myList">contact</li>
        <li id="fpn2" class="myList">about</li>
        <li id="fpn3" class="myList">careers</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="mainBodyContent" id="Contact">
    <div class="perimgleft">
        <img class="perImg" alt="This is for sample" />
        <div id="thisID3">
            <p><span>sample1</span>
            </p>
            <p>To explore job opputunities at 'Company', see our <a name="Career" href="#Careers"><span>Hot Jobs</span></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mainBodyContent" id="About">
    <div class="perimgleft">
        <img class="perImg" alt="This is for sample" />
        <div id="thisID2">
            <p><span>sample2</span>
            </p>
            <p>To explore job opputunities at 'Company', see our <a name="Career" href="#Careers"><span>Hot Jobs</span></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mainBodyContent" id="Careers">
    <div class="perimgleft">
        <img class="perImg" alt="This is for sample" />
        <div id="thisID1">
            <p><span>sample3</span>
            </p>
            <p>To explore job opputunities at 'Company', see our <a name="Career" href="#Careers"><span>Hot Jobs</span></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>

var hover1 = $("#Contact");
var hover2 = $("#About");
var hover3 = $("#Careers");


$(".myList").mouseout(function(evt) {
    $('.mainBodyContent').css('display','none');

});
$(".myList").mouseover(function(evt) {

    var currentId=$(this).attr('id');

    if(currentId=='fpn1'){
        hover1.css({'display':'block'});
    }
    if(currentId=='fpn2'){
        hover2.css({'display':'block'});
    }
    if(currentId=='fpn3'){
        hover3.css({'display':'block'});
    }
});



</script>
</body>


 </html>
```